# Coefficient estimates are different in the dot whisker plot than in the model summary

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to plot my regression models using dwplot() command.

However, the resulting plot shows different estimates than in my model summary. Any idea how this could happen?

Given below is my code.

```
#model for weight_birth

birth_wt<- subset(bball_new,select=c(weight_birth_pp,
                                  maternal_age,
                                  ethnicity,
                                  smoking_antenatal,
                                  marital_status,
                                  highest_education,
                                  occupational_status,
                                  previous_births,
                                  mode_delivery,
                                  antenatal_multivits,
                                  antenatal_iron,
                                  antenatal_folicacid,
                                  gdm_status,
                                  prenatal_bmi,
                                  net_wt_gain,
                                  gestational_age,
                                  infant_sex))

str(birth_wt)

birth_wt_no<-lm(weight_birth_pp~1, birth_wt)
birth_wt_all<-lm(weight_birth_pp~., birth_wt)

mod_birth_wt<-step(birth_wt_no, direction = "forward",formula(birth_wt_all))
summary(mod_birth_wt)

dwplot(mod_birth_wt)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Having a reproducible example makes it much easier to help you.  Can you include some of your data (*e.g* with `dput(birth_wt)` or `dput(head(birth_wt))`) ?

Comment: Thank you RoB. I have edited my post with results from dput(birth_wt) and summary. I am not allowed to add images.